# What is the equivalent of 'head :ok' from Rails in Phoenix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to return a response that has no content (merely headers) like [this one](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Head/head)

```
def show
  head :ok
end
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [Plug.Conn.send_resp/3](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#send_resp/3) with empty body:

```
# 200 OK
send_resp(conn, 200, "")
send_resp(conn, :ok, "") # same as above
# 401 Unauthorized
send_resp(conn, 401, "")
send_resp(conn, :unauthorized, "") # same as above
```

`send_resp` can take the status (second argument) as an integer or one of the supported atoms mentioned here: https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.Status.html#code/1.

Answer (score 3):

@dogbert answers was spot on. Additionally you can read up on relevant documentation from official [phoenix guide](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/overview). The relevant information - http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/controllers#section-sending-responses-directly

> ...Let's
>   say we want to send a response with a status of "201" and no body
>   whatsoever. We can easily do that with the send_resp/3 function.

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  conn
  |> send_resp(201, "")
end
```