# Sending an empty response in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How do I send an empty response from a controller in Phoenix?

I'm looking for the equivalent of `render :nothing => true` in Rails and have found `text("")` so far, but it doesn't seem right?

Comment: Is this what you want: [What is the equivalent of 'head :ok' from Rails in Phoenix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317594/what-is-the-equivalent-of-head-ok-from-rails-in-phoenix)?

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was trying to find, thanks!